# Updating values with another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, replace, dataframe

I have 2 pandas dataframes. The second one is contained in the first one. How can I replace the values in the first one with the ones in the second?

consider this example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(0, index=[1,2,3], columns=['a','b','c'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(1, index=[1, 2], columns=['a', 'c'])

ris= [[1, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 1],
      [0, 0, 0]]
```

and `ris` has the same index and columns of `d1`

A possible solution is:

```
for i in df2.index:
  for j in df2.columns:
     df1.loc[i, j] = df2.loc[i, j]
```

But this is ugly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) with [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df3 = df1.copy()
df1[df2.columns] = df2[df2.columns]
print df1.combine_first(df3) 
     a  b    c
1  1.0  0  1.0
2  1.0  0  1.0
3  0.0  0  0.0
```

Next solution is creating empty new `DataFrame` `df4` with `index` and `columns` from `df1` and fill it by double [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame(index=df1.index, columns=df1.columns)
df4 = df4.combine_first(df2).combine_first(df1)
print df4
     a    b    c
1  1.0  0.0  1.0
2  1.0  0.0  1.0
3  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
In [7]: df1['a'] = df2['a']

In [8]: df1['c'] = df2['c']

In [14]: df1[['a','c']] = df2[['a','c']]
```

If the column names are not known:

```
In [25]: for col in df2.columns:
   ....:     df1[col] = df2[col]
```